# NSPredicate over different entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I want to make NSPredicate over different entities. Here is my core database.

[image]

To make it simple, this is the query I should do.

```
Select c.c_name From Company c, Person p Where c.c_id = p.cu_company_id
```

Now I was wondering how my predicate should look like if I want to achieve the result like the query above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that c_id and cu_company_id are integers, you can try

```
    NSFetchRequest *fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    NSError *error;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cu_company_id == data.company.c_id"];
    [fr setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *persons = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fr error:&error];
```

and once you have persons array, you can then loop through it and get the person's name. To get it the other way around

```
    NSFetchRequest *fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Company"];
    NSError *error;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"c_id == data.person.cu_company_id"];
    [fr setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *companies = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fr error:&error];
```

and once you have companies array, you can then loop through it and get the company's name.

Comment: I'm sorry, I need the company's name not the persons name.

Comment: It is the same thing, other way around. It is easy to just think in terms of Objects, instead of tables and rows and columns. I edited the answer.

Comment: Oké but what If I need a person Object, and don't want from this person object the company-id but the company-name. Should I make two seperate fetch requests ?